# BIM 360 field API login issues

Tags: api, rest, field, autodesk

Frustrating issue with attempting to use REST to login to the BIM 360 Field API, it was suggested that to use the postman application in order to ensure that my code wasn't an issue, however I'm now getting an unauthorized error, this has been attempted with an admin account and a developer account with the same response (login details are definitely valid), I was wandering if anyone has encountered this problem before or has any idea how would go about getting past this, I need to get the ticket response in order to go any further with developing an application for this, I'm already in contact with someone from Autodesk but due to timezone differences responses are difficult!

I've attached a picture to highlight the simplicity of what I'm attempting to do with no joy!

Thanks in advance

Dan

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else hits the same issue, FYI -

Dan and I looked at this issue, and we learned (in a hard way) that the base URL for BIM 360 Field in European region is:

https://bim360field.eu.autodesk.com

Notice "eu" in the URL. In the U.S., it is https://bim360field.autodesk.com

I wrote a post about this, too, for future reference: 
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/18/base-url-for-bim-360-field-in-european-countries/

Answer (score -1):

I also found it worked when I used https but not http although the examples in the help use http.

Comment: This doesn't appear to resolve the predicament the OP is facing.